# Trying to force install a chrome extension for all users

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, google-chrome, extension, chrome

I'm trying to force install an extension called 'Grammarly' for all users on a session host server.

I have copied the necessary files to C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions and when I run gpedit.msc, I can see under Local computer policy\Administrative Templates the 'Google' option; So far so good.

I go to google, into google chrome and into extensions and I modify the 'Configure the list of force-installed apps and extensions' item.

I have Grammarly installed on my own machine, and by going to chrome://extensions, I can see its extension ID is **kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen**
If I go to my AppData and find this extension and check out its manifest, I can see its update URL is **https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx**

This means the value for Grammarly should be 
**kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx** as far as I can tell.

I have put this in on the session host and applied it, then I've run gpupdate and logged off. When I logged back in, I'd expect Grammarly to install, but it does not. Nothing happens.
When I browse to chrome://extensions, It tells me I have no extensions installed.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: As far as I can see you did everything you should. Is the server domain joined? What are the results of `gpresult /h result.html`? Is the policy being applied?

Comment: It is domain joined, but I'm having an issue with domain group policy... I suspect there is an underlying issue with the DC's syncing, but thats another story..... hence the reason I went down the local group policy route.

running gpresult seems to only show domain group policies.

Comment: Policies are applied like this: **L**ocal-**S**ite-**D**omain-**OU**, so maybe it gets overwritten. I'd say check why your GPOs don't get applied and try again, because your approach seems to be correct.